# How to use rails 'get' in a rspec test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

Inside a controller spec I have the following code...

```
    subject do
      get 'index'
      puts 'response is ' + response.body
      JSON.parse(response.body)
    end
```

This works fine, getting the index action for the specific api controller.  However when I try a show request, I don't know how to pass in a variable, so when I run...

```
    subject do
      get 'show'
      puts 'response is ' + response.body
      JSON.parse(response.body)
    end
```

I get the error...

```
 ←[31mFailure/Error:←[0m ←[31mget 'show'←[0m
 ←[31mActionController::RoutingError←[0m:
   ←[31mNo route matches {:controller=>"api/example/v1/clinics", :action=>"show"}←[0m
```

There is a show action for the api/example/v1/clinics, of course I didn't pass the parameter which it needs, unsure how to do that.  How would I get a show action working?

I tried something like

```
    get 'api/example/v1/clinics/2'
```

but that does not work either.  I can't seem to locate the documentation for this rails method either.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: How about something like: `get :show, id: 1` assuming your route requires an id to be passed.

Comment: @Brian: ha that works who knew it would be so easy :) its actually get :show, :id => 1

Comment: if you add that as an answer I'll accept it thanks :)

Comment: No worries, it was a quick one & easy to overlook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For controller actions that require parameters (for example 'id' is required by the show action) you need to pass it as a parameter to the get request:

```
get :show, id: 1
```

Or if using older 1.8 hash syntax:

```
get :show, :id => 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in an id to `get :show` by:

```
get 'show', id: 2
```